# docker + apt-add-repository: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte

Tags: docker, character-encoding

After starting a fresh docker Ubuntu environment,

```
docker run -ti ubuntu:17.04
```

I'm trying to add a PPA via

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y software-properties-common
apt-add-repository -y ppa:nschloe/vtk7-nightly
```

However, this fails with

```
gpg: key ECD154D280FEB8AC: public key "Launchpad PPA for Nico Schl�mer" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 229: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Looks like the dreaded `ö` umlaut strikes again.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just set a UTF-8 aware locale, before you invoke the `apt-add-repository`:

```
export LANG=C.UTF-8
```

and it will work just fine.

Comment: This also works for the same type of run.time error in combination with the Python tool docker-squash.